# The action of an extension group $G=p^{1+2n}{.}Q$ on the faithful characters of its normal subgroup $p^{1+2n}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let  $G=p^{1+2n}{.}Q$, $n>1$, be a finite extension group of an extra-special $p$-group $N=p^{1+2n}$ by a group $Q$, where $Q$ is a linear group of dimension $2n$ over $GF(p)$. It seems that the action (by conjugation) of $G$ (or $Q$) on the $p-1$ irreducible faithful characters of $N$ is transitive. If it is the case, how does one show it? For example, let we consider the maximal subgroup $3_+^{1+4}{:}4S_6$ of $Co_3$.

Comment: It you have a direct product, (and $p>2$) it is certainly not transitive. Also if $|Q|<p-1$.

Comment: Since you haven't given us any information about $Q$, this is impossible to answer. $Q$ could be the trivial group.

Comment: The group $Q$ Is a $2n$-dimensional linear group over $GF(p)$.

Comment: That still doesn't rule out $Q$ being trivial.

Comment: Lets take $n>1$.

Comment: Taking $n>1$ does not prevent $Q$ being trivial.

Comment: Let we consider maximal subgroup $3_+^{1+4}{:}4S_6$ of $Co_3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129787/discussion-between-isaac-and-derek-holt).

Comment: $Q$ is necessarily a subgroup of $GSp_{2g}$, and there is a map $GSp_{2g}(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb F_p^\times$ with kernel $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb F_p)$. The action is transitive if and only if the image of $G$ under this map is surjective.

Comment: $3_+^{1+4}:4S_6$ has trivial centre, so the two faithful characters of the extraspecial group are interchanged in that example.

Comment: Just want to now, why $Q$ is necessarily  a subgroup of $GSp_{2g}$?

Comment: In general, $Q$ is transitive on the faithful characters of $E$ if and only if it is transitive in its conjugation action on $Z(E) \setminus \{1\}$ (where $E$ is the extraspecial group), which might make it easier to determine.